# Zoom on a room in the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

Now, I'm able to list the levels. I'm trying to zoom on a specific room of a given level.

I've the room `dbId` but when I do this :

`v.fitToView(34969, v.model)` (v => viewer / 34969 the dbId's room)

Camera is going to far :

[image]

I'm trying to do exactly the same camera movement than when I click on a sub item in `modelStructureTool > Room`

#### about color of a room

Here is my code with the correction :

```
var ulRoom = document.createElement('ul');
ulRoom.setAttribute('id','levelsList');
el.children.forEach(function(l){
var liRoom = document.createElement('li');
liRoom.setAttribute('class','room');
liRoom.setAttribute('style','cursor:pointer;color:  #000; font-weigth: bold');
liRoom.onclick = function () {
    console.log("l ====>", l);
    viewer.fitToView( [l.dbId], viewer.model);
    viewer.setThemingColor( l.dbId, viewer.model);
    };
    ulRoom.appendChild(liRoom);
    liRoom.innerHTML = l.name;
});
```

`viewer.fitToView` is working nicely.

In my `forEach`, `l` is room :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument must be an array, so your function call has to be changed to `viewer.fitToView( [ 34969 ], viewer.model )`. The 2nd argument `model` is optional, so it will become `viewer.fitToView( [ 34969 ] )` in single model use case.

If you’re using the Viewer in multiple models case, you have to find the corresponding model from `viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()` for that room and the second argument of the `Viewer3D#fitToView`.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

The viewer API for changing element's color is `viewer.setThemingColor( dbId, color )` and it only works for leaf nodes. After investigating the model you provided to Forge Helpdesk, I found the room which has dbId `34969` is not the leaf node of the Viewer instance tree. So, this's why the color didn't change while the API is event right.

```
function getLeafNodes( model, dbIds ) {

      return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

        try {

          const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree

          dbIds = dbIds || instanceTree.getRootId();

          const dbIdArray = Array.isArray( dbIds ) ? dbIds : [dbIds]
          let leafIds = [];

          const getLeafNodesRec = ( id ) => {
            let childCount = 0;

            instanceTree.enumNodeChildren( id, ( childId ) => {
                getLeafNodesRec( childId );

                ++childCount;
              })

            if( childCount == 0 ) {
              leafIds.push( id );
            }
          }

          for( let i = 0; i < dbIdArray.length; ++i ) {
            getLeafNodesRec( dbIdArray[i] );
          }

          return resolve( leafIds );

        } catch (ex) {

          return reject(ex)
        }
    })
}

let color = new THREE.Vector4( 255/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1 );

getLeafNodes( viewer.model, [ 34969 ] )
    .then( ( leafNodes ) => {

      // Call setThemingColor for every leaf node.
      for( let i = 0; i < leafNodes.length; i++ ) {
          viewer.setThemingColor( leafNodes[i], color );
      }
    })
    .catch( ( error ) => console.warn( error ) );
```

Here is the Viewer documentation: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/

Comment: if you can tell me how to change the color of this dbId element, it will be perfect :)

Comment: Here you go ~ ‘viewer.setThemingColor( dbId, model )’ model is optional, if second argument is null, viewer will use viewer.model by default.

Comment: I have try this but without success : `viewer.fitToView( [l.dbId], viewer.model); viewer.setThemingColor( l.dbId, viewer.model);`
`l.dbId` is a Room...

Comment: What is your `l` and your raw model format, RVT or NWD?

Comment: `l` is the room : `{…}​children: Array [ {…} ]​dbId: 34985​name: "Living Room"​__proto__: Object { … } `

Comment: The `dbId` should be the type of number, you can use `parseInt( dbId )` as the function input to ensure your dbId is a number. For example, `viewer.fitToView( [ parseInt( 34969 ) ] )` or `viewer.setThemingColor( parseInt( dbId ) )`

Comment: I've edit my initial post. Can you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Is your forge app accessible from outside? Or could you consider providing a non-confidential reproducible case which contains this model and a simple Forge Viewer app to `forge.help@autodesk.com`? it needs  to debug.

Comment: My apologies, I have a mistake for the changing element's color, the API should be `viewer.setThemingColor( dbId, color )`, I have updated my answer above, please take a look.